# Getting blank map for native maps build using Cordova/Ionic 2

Tags: cordova, google-maps, ionic2, cordova-plugins, android-maps-v2

I am working on a Ionic 2 app that implements Cordova's Native Maps plugin. I followed this guide here https://www.joshmorony.com/integrating-native-google-maps-into-an-ionic-2-application/. I followed everything the guide says, however, when I load the app to my Android device, I just see a screen that contains the zoom controls, the location button, and even the Google water mark. It's as if everything loaded, however the maps never appear. I did get an error when emulating that says

> PANIC: Can not find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

but I think that's just an emulation problem. Could it be a problem with the key? The guide didn't explain how to get the iOS key so maybe that's the problem. Any other ideas or suggestions?

Comment: is your `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable set?

Comment: Yeah I do. What's confusing is that all of my previous ionic builds work completely fine, it's just the map that's getting this error. Does it matter if it's in my User Variables or System Variables? Because right now I have everything in User Variables

Comment: No..have you created an emulator device?  Also add the code where you are setting the map..

Comment: Yeah, I just did that. I updated everything and created an emulator device. That fixed the `PANIC: Can not find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` problem, but the map is still blank. All of my code can be found from this guide https://www.joshmorony.com/integrating-native-google-maps-into-an-ionic-2-application/ The only thing that I believe I'm missing from this guide is the Android Support Library -- I couldn't find that in my SDK Manager

Answer (score 0):

When ever you see a blank map with zoom controls and locations button. There is always an issue with the key . please search how to create correct key...